# How to add product in cart in react?

Tags: reactjs

This my code for header app.js and iphone.js.
I want to get access to name and image of product when I click on Add to Cart button on iphone.js.

```js
//app.js

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigationbar from "./header";
import Home from "./Home";
import ContactForm from "./Contact";
import RegistrationForm from "./SignUp";
import LogIn from "./LogIn";
import Footer from "./footer";
import Iphone from "./Iphone";
import Sony from "./Sony";
import Oneplus from "./Oneplus";
import Nokia from "./Nokia";
import Vivo from "./Vivo";
import Oppo from "./Oppo";
import Cart from "./Cart";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Router>
         <Navigationbar />
         <div className="pages">
         <Switch>
           <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
           <Route path='/Contact' component={ContactForm}/>
           <Route path='/SignUp' component={RegistrationForm}/>
           <Route path='/LogIn' component={LogIn}/>
           <Route path='/Iphone' component={Iphone}/>
           <Route path='/Oppo' component={Oppo}/>
           <Route path='/Sony' component={Sony}/>
           <Route path='/Oneplus' component={Oneplus}/>
           <Route path='/Vivo' component={Vivo}/>
           <Route path='/Nokia' component={Nokia}/>
           <Route path='/Cart' component={Cart}/>
         </Switch>
       </div>
       <Footer />
     </Router>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

```js
//Header.js

import { Nav, Navbar, NavLink } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Navigationbar = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>
        iStore
        <img src="/apple.png" class="apple" alt="No " />
      </h1>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="sm"  variant="dark" Style="padding-bottom:0;">
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
          <Nav>
            <NavLink eventKey="1" as={Link} to="/">Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink eventKey="2" as={Link} to="/Contact">Contact</NavLink>
            <NavLink eventKey="3" as={Link} to="/SignUp">SignUp</NavLink>
            <NavLink eventKey="4" as={Link} to="/LogIn">LogIn</NavLink>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        <form  role="search">
          <input class="search me-4" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div className="Cartdiv">
          <p>{cart.length}</p>
          <NavLink Style="padding-top:0;" eventKey="5" as={Link} to="/Cart">
            <button className="cart">
              <img src="cart.png" className="cart"/>
            </button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Navigationbar;
```

```js
//iphone.js

import React, { useState } from "react";

const iphone = [
  {productid:1, name:"iphone1", image:"/iphone9.jpg"},
  {productid:2, name:"iphone2", image:"/iphone2.jpg"},
  {productid:3, name:"iphone3", image:"/iphone3.jpg"},
  {productid:4, name:"iphone4", image:"/iphone15.jpg"},
  {productid:5, name:"iphone5", image:"/iphone20.webp"},
  {productid:6, name:"iphone6", image:"/iphone6.jpg"},
  {productid:7, name:"iphone7", image:"/iphone7.jpg"},
  {productid:8, name:"iphone8", image:"/iphone8.jpeg"}
];

function Iphone(props){
  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    name: "",
    image: ""
  });

  function submitProduct(event) {
    props.onAdd(note);
    setNote({
      name: event.target.item.name,
      image:event.target.item.image,
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div class="iphonefurther">
      <div class="row">
        {iphone.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 elementss zoom ">
              <form>
                <div class="container111">
                  <img class="iphoness" src={item.image} />
                  <h5>{item.name}</h5>
                  <button type="submit" Style="width:186px;" onClick={submitProduct} class=" btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Iphone;
```

I want to add the name and image value to the header cart array so that when i click on the cart button in header it renders me a cart.js with  name and image.

Comment: Please try again to format your post for clarity. Familiarize yourself with the simple tools in the editor rather than writing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally render some info, like the items currently in your cart, you can try creating a state called isOpen, and then when the user clicks a button you can change the isOpen state to true or false, and then do a conditional render of the info in your cart with:

```
{ isOpen && <Code /> }
```

Here the code in  will only be displayed if isOpen is true. And then you can hide the data if you set isOpen to false.

Comment: i just when i click on the add to the add cart button it save the name and image value to the array as an object so that i can access it in the header section.